# Where are all the `alternatives` stored?

Tags: alternative

As far as I understand, `/etc/alternatives` stores only currently selected alternatives. Where are all the variants and all the metadata stored? I have accidentally removed an alternative with `galternatives` and want to add it back as it was manually (as `galternatives` functionality is very limited).

Answer (score 1):

This data seems to be in /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives, also check man update-alternatives for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The command-line `update-alternatives` tool should help you here.

This command should take you through all alternatives one at a time:

`update-alternatives --all`

[There are some more examples at this wiki page](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) which can show you all manually-set alternatives and even (use with caution!) reset all those to their defaults.

A more detailed description of how the alternatives system works, including where it stores all its configuration, is available [in the update-alternatives manpage](http://man.he.net/man8/update-alternatives) (note that this version for Debian and Ubuntu contains more functionality than the update-alternatives from redhat).